# relative positioning and clickable anchor

Tags: css

I have 2 questions which I would love some help with!

1. I have a child a tag inside a footer and i want to position this a halfway outside this footer. i have tried the following.

   ```
   footer a(or id of the anchor) {
   position:relative;
   top:-50px;
   z-index:100;
   background:url(../img/toTopLink.png);
   display:block;
   }

   footer {
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   }
   ```

   It positions itself outside the footer so that’s all swell, but the part of the `<a>` tag that’s outside of the footer doesn’t show, it gets clipped. Why is that? I thought z-index would take care of that. It doesn’t work with absolute positioning either and thats not an option since im doing a responsive layout.
2. This `<a>` tag with its background image is supposed to be clickable, but when I use `text-indent` to remove the text from sight, the `<a>` with the background picture is no longer clickable. I’ve set it to display block and have tried using padding too.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: do you have any online link to see your problem.. or atleast gv a http://jsfiddle.net/ link...

Comment: here is an example. why isnt the square clicable? noob question i know.. http://jsfiddle.net/stinis87/K5NDe/9/

Comment: never mind, i solved it. i lacked the "=" before the id..:p

Answer (score 0):

For the position question.
CSS

```
footer a {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    ...
}
```

For the click question. If you don't want to show a text, don't insert it (you can use `title` attribute for SEO stuff). In order to keep the image clickable, being an empty `a`, I suggest:
CSS

```
footer a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i solved the first question, forgot that i had visibility hidden on. But for the second question. I tried removing the anchor text and use only title for seo. I have the anchor as display block and it has a height, width and a background image. Shouldnt this be enough to make it clickable?

Comment: Yes, it should be enough, can you provide a link or online test? Something in your code seems to break the anchor behaviour.

Comment: i know..i dont have a host unforunately, only have my page local.